# Есть ли синтаксическая ошибка + лексическая ошибка?

Tags: синтаксис, лексика, лексическая-сочетаемость, придаточное-предложение

"Ваши результаты — число фирм, чью бухгалтерию вы вели, и в течение какого срока, какие виды отчётности вы составляли и сколько раз".

Правомерно ли с точки зрения синтаксиса делать так, что продолжение главного предложения "в течение какого срока" неразрывно связано с предшествующим придаточным "чью бухгалтерию вы вели", т.е. придаточное нельзя изъять без потери смысла?

Можно ли использовать относительное местоимение "чей" в качестве союзного слова, если оно относится к неодушевленному предмету?

Answer (score 3):

*[Ваши результаты — число фирм], (чью бухгалтерию вы вели) и (в течение какого срока),( какие виды отчётности вы предоставляли)  и (сколько раз).*

... чью бухгалтерию вы вели и в течение какого срока - это однородные  придаточные предложения, второе неполное: вы вели(что?)бухгалтерию (чью?) и ( когда вы её вели?) Если сочтёте однородными членами,(что тоже возможно с другим подходом к анализу предложения-чью и когда?) всё равно запятой нет.

А лексическая ошибка в замене слов: **составляют** отчётность, а виды отчётности **предоставляют**.

Местоимение на месте. Можно же сказать "Заря, чей свет..."

Comment: Имеется в виду именно составление, т.е. её заполнение соответствующих форм отчётности.

Comment: Я всё же не могу понять, как "в течение какого срока" может быть однородным придаточным, если по смыслу это относится к результатам? То, в течение какого срока бухгалтерия велась, также является результатом. Мне кажется ваш синтаксический разбор неверным. Мне он видится следующим образом: [Ваши результаты — число фирм, (чью бухгалтерию вы вели), и в течение какого срока, какие виды отчётности вы предоставляли и сколько раз]. "Число фирм", "в течение какого срока", "какие виды отчётности" и "сколько раз" являются однородными сказуемыми с подлежащим "ваши результаты".

Comment: Вот именно, как Вы заметили, результаты - это число фирм и ТО..., и ТО..., и ТО.... Это четыре сказуемых, три из которых пропущены. Если их восстановить, получится: Ваши результаты — число фирм, (чью бухгалтерию вы вели), и то,( в течение какого срока вы её вели), то,( какие виды отчётности вы составляли), и то, ( сколько раз вы их  составляли). В течение какого срока - это обстоятельство, а не сказуемое.

Comment: Вы правы в том, что это не однородное подчинение, а как раз неоднородное соподчинение, все придаточные относятся к разным словам в главном. Запятой нет, потому что однородные сказуемые "число" и "то", "то" и "то". Но ТО пропущены, поэтому затрудняется понимание смысла.

Answer (score 3):

Обращает на себя внимание *недостаточная связь* между перечисляемыми критериями (фирмы сами по себе, "сроки" можно отнести как к их бухгалтерии, так и  к "видам отчётности" - то ли при этих работах, то ли отдельно от них). Местоимение "чью" в таких контекстах *лучше избегать* (не то чтобы ошибка, а стиль это здесь портит, создаёт впечатление одушевлённости и напыщенности, это почти то же, что вне поэтического текста сказать "*о ты, Конституция, чьи статьи в моём сознании весомы.*..").

> Ваши результаты оцениваются числом фирм, бухгалтерию *которых* вы вели,
>   а также тем, в течение какого срока вы *это делали*, какие виды
>   отчётности и сколько раз вы *при этом* составляли.

Comment: Исходная фраза составлена так, что не оставляет сомнений: ведение бухгалтерии неких фирм — один вид работы, составление отчетов — другой. Если же на деле составление отчетов является частью процесса ведению бухгалтерии, то исходная фраза просто неверно построена, а исправление, предложенное Alex_ander, принципиально необходимо.